# LDO 3.3V Overheats on DC input and no load

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo, 3.3v

XC6206P332MR 662K 3.3V 200mA TOREX LDO Voltage Regulator SMD SOT-23

The capacitors on Vin and Vout are not too close, maybe 1cm away from the pins,
I've tried anything from 0.1uF to 22uf, Im powering the LDO from a 4.2 Lipo,
It's the second LDO from a second supplier I'm trying.

Considering my input is DC, I'm a little confused why it's overheating. It appears to be drawing 200ma.
Behaves the same with no load or if I connect a 1k resistor for some load.

I haven't tried an oscilloscope yet though to see if there's some instability.
It is my first SMD circuit, I've used non SMT 3.3v regulators before without any issues.

Ordered and soldered two new 1uf ceramic capacitors as advised, did not change the outcome however. my caps could definitely be placed a lot better.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) include a schematic (yes even though it will be an obvious one). 2) are you 100% sure you're connecting it correctly ? Remeasure (continuity check with multimeter on unpowered board) anyway. 3) are you using **ceramic** 1uF caps as indicated in the XC6206 datasheet ?

Comment: 4) if you must answer 2) or 3) with **no** then the LDOs might be damaged already. It is always better to check PCBs when powered from a **lab supply** with **current limiting** at 50 mA or so. A charged LiPo cell can **destroy** any IC in a fraction of a micro second when connected in the wrong way (like reversed supply). Oops !

Comment: I seem to be using Tanatalum capacitors... Descriptions of similar problems talked of importance of the capacitors, but also of high frequencies etc, but I figured this is DC so not so crucial..I guess I need to buy some ceramics and try with a fresh LDO? Ive checked the wiring many times, it doesnt seem to be the probem.

Comment: I might have used one of these capacitors with the curuit, theres no specification what type they are visible to me, i guess if they caused the overheat, then ldo is already gone.. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/16values-20pcs-320pcs-1206-SMD-Capacitor-assorted-kit-10pF-22uF-component-diy-samples-kit-new-and/32623067420.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.gtHZif

Comment: Tantalum caps ! Oops ! They were popular in the late 1990s ;-) when I was a rookie-engineer. Yes this is a DC circuit but the caps are needed to make the LDO stable. And these modern chips can easily oscillate at a **couple of 100 MHz** where a Tantalum cap is **no good**. Ceramic caps are much better at such frequencies, they might still even behave as a cap (and not  an inductor !). So get some **ceramic caps** !

Comment: Thank you will do! Will post results and/or my actual diagrams if the problem persists!~

Comment: Those from the link appear to be ceramic ! Cheap but not Tantalum. These are tantalum: http://www.hkcapacitor.com/catalog.asp?tags=Chip+Tantalum+Capacitor  Note that they have a **minus side**.

Comment: Also: you don't want to place these caps 1 cm or so away, but as close as possible to the pins, that is to reduce the inductance and also the loop area, which both might cause troubles.

Comment: @KrzysztofStankiewicz - I recommend you edit your question to add a close-up, in-focus photo of your circuit board, showing the regulator and surrounding components (capacitors etc.) and wiring. That will help readers to identify capacitor types and other relevant details.

Comment: _"Considering my input is DC, I'm a little confused why it's overheating?"_ - Why do you think that "DC input" guarantees "no overheating"? What's your reasoning there?

Comment: @marcelm I don't expect instability from the LDO, since it's essentially an op-amp circuit the way I understand it, and there are no external frequencies... Yeah, I didn't expect any oscillations.. (Could be/Most likely are happening here)

Comment: Instability has nothing to do with external frequencies. The opamp will happely start oscillating by itself. 
You mention 200 mA currentdraw, which seems to be the current-limit amount of the device. What is the output voltage? Sounds a lot like a shortcircuit on the output somewhere.

Comment: @JorenVaes I will post pictures of my diagram tomorrow. But as I've mentioned, I left the output unconnected, and also tried with 1kOhm resistor for load.. Didn't make a difference. Ground pin seemed to be the one overheating. Yes 200mah is the limit and it was drawing no more than 200mah, If I had a short circuit a lipo could discharge at much more than that.. its a 700mah battery so even 7A wouldnt be unexpected..

Comment: First: small nit pick -don't mix mah (which I assume comes from mAh, or milli-Ampere-hours) and mA (which is milli-Ampere, or 0.001 A). 
Second: The current that goes in has to go to ground somewhere - either it does so internaly because the regulator is damaged, or it does so externaly, because the output sees a (undesired) short to ground. The reason I suspect it's on the output is because the 200 mA seem to indicate the regulator is working and in current-limit mode. Hence, perhaps due to a soldering issue, or board damage or such, the output is shorted to ground. Check with a multimeter.

Comment: Just because you don't intentionally short the device, does not mean there is no unintentional short circuit due to a board error or soldering error or such.

Comment: The picture says LM1117, the schematic says LM3480 and your post says XR6206. All of them have incompatible pinouts, so my guess is that this is simply a pinout error and the chip you soldered is now burned...

Answer (score 1):

Like @peufeu states, it is not clear what voltage regulator you really were planning to use, but if we should go by the schematics, it is the LM3480, and that is what the layout is suggesting (as far as I can see from the potato vision image attached) I can tell you right away, that if you as you state in the question -
 were trying to mount a XC6206 on the footprint for U4 from your picture, it will of course not work as expected. Have you even read the datasheets for the parts you use? The physical pinouts are literally on the first pages of the datasheets.

This is essentially what you have connected:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc75FX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the block diagram for the XC6206 (Taken from the [Datasheet](https://www.torexsemi.com/file/xc6206/XC6206.pdf):
[image]

I don't think I will have to tell you why this is heating up, do I?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write the answer! Gotta  solder the chip upside down or sideways to fix this...

Comment: I didn't notice the XC6206 has a different pinout. Thank you for pointing that out. Initially I was using the lm3480 and the pintout seems to agree with my schematic. I had trouble with the lm3480 as stated in the initial question, so i went onto the xc6206 because i did not trust the supplier and i thought the lm3480 should have just worked, so i thought perhaps they sent me the wrong part. i just tried a fresh lm3480 on the pcb again and it seems to be overheating as before. i will reorder it i think, not xc6206 but another lm3480 as per my initial design.